# Monotouch - Phone Will Not Vibrate

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I cant seem to get my phone to vibrate when calling the vibrate method.

SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound();

It looks like there is a bug filed that show the same thing but I cant believe it would not be fixed yet.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7983

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: post a comment on the bug asking for a status update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling it from the UI thread?
I learned many problems with the APIs are solved when invoking them in the UI thread by using `InvokeOnMainThread`

Comment: Hmmm, thats a good point.  I actually am pretty sure I am not on the UIThread.  I will give that a try.  Thanks.

Comment: Still no luck, I tried      InvokeOnMainThread(delegate 
    {
     SystemSound.Vibrate.PlayAlertSound ();
    });